# How to get variables from config file in powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters, config

How can i get variables from a config file in XML ?

I am actualy doing this using a .txt config file.

There is my actual code :

Config.txt

```
[Repertoire de SPO (generalement C:\SPO)]
destinationn="C:\SPO"

[Nom du sous repertoire de SPO (generalement : SPO1)]
sous_destination="SPO1"

[Numero de la version de SPO vers laquelle vous souhaitez upgrade (par exemple : 1812.4)]
version="1812.4"

[Nom du pool dapplication lie a SPO (par defaut SPO_ADV)]
applicationPoolName="SPO_ADV"

[Chemin de livraison de la nouvelle version de SPO (par defaut \\path\to\somewhere)]
livraisonn="\\path\to\somewhere"
```

Powershell.ps1

```
Get-Content "$current_path\config.txt" | foreach-object -begin {$h=@{}} -process { $k = [regex]::split($_,'='); if(($k[0].CompareTo("") -ne 0) -and ($k[0].StartsWith("[") -ne $True)) { $h.Add($k[0], $k[1]) } }

$destinationn = $h.Get_Item("destinationn")
```

I would like to do a similar thing using an .xml config file.

Comment: You may want to have a look at the Script `Get-IniContent` from the [TechNet Gallery](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/ea40c1ef-c856-434b-b8fb-ebd7a76e8d91and) which enables you to "parse" an `ini`-like file to return the values as a Hashtable

Comment: If you are open to reading JSON ot INI (i.e. TXT) files, consider https://github.com/alekdavis/ConfigFile

Comment: There is a much more convenient way to read settings using the `ConvertFrom-Json` Cmdlet in PowerShell to read a JSON formatted file: https://serverfault.com/a/1032517/293696

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Xml is much easier to parse with PowerShell. See following example with comments:

```
#Translated XML config
@'
<root>
  <destinationn>C:\SPO</destinationn>
  <sous_destination>SPO1</sous_destination>
  <version>1812.4</version>
  <applicationPoolName>SPO_ADV</applicationPoolName>
  <livraisonn>\\path\to\somewhere</livraisonn>
</root>
'@ | Out-File YourSampleConfig.xml

#read xml file, skip root
$config = ([xml](Get-Content YourSampleConfig.xml)).root

#get <destinationn> value
$config.destinationn
```

Comment: What is the "root" for here ?

Comment: `root` is main, required node in xml: `<root>...<root>`. Name it whatever you want. If you name it `<ABC>...</ABC>`, you must chage it to `ABC` in script as well.

Answer (score 3):

#### Getting connection string from App.Config

```
$appConfigFile = [IO.Path]::Combine($currentDirectory, '.\MyFile.config')
```

#### initialize the xml object

```
$appConfig = New-Object XML
```

#### load the config file as an xml object

```
$appConfig.Load($appConfigFile)
```

#### iterate over the settings which you want

```
foreach ($connectionString in $appConfig.configuration.connectionStrings.add) {
    # Get the connection string
    $dbconnectionstring = $connectionString.connectionString
}
```

Here's my config xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="AtomicScopeConStr" connectionString="Server= localhost; Database= mydatabase; Integrated Security=True;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This was a great help. See the working code in the answer below. (which is slightly different from above). My config file was essentially identical to the one above. Same elements.

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow up to HariHaran's post. My connection.config file had the same elements and structure as his, but my working code is slightly different.

Use this to load the xml object

```
$appConfig = New-Object XML
$appConfig.Load($appConfigFile)
```

or use this

```
[xml]$appConfig = Get-Content $appConfigFile
```

and here is the working code to get the connection string

```
foreach ($xmlAddElement in $appConfig.connectionStrings.add) {
    $connectionString = $xmlAddElement.connectionString
    Write-Host "$connectionString"
}
```